# Passing data to Cocoa Quartz event tap callback - bad casting from void*

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, casting

I am writing a simple logging program in Cocoa.

I create my callback function to log pressed keys into file, but here comes the problem. I have file handler in my AppDelegate and I can't reach it from inside the callback function.

I tried to pass it inside via last parameter of callback function (the `void*` one), but inside i have to cast it back to NSFileHandle - but to do that I have to "bridge-cast" it. But whether I use `__bridge` or `__bridge_transfer` the program crashes.

I am new to Objective-C so maybe I am missing something obvious, but I had searched "all" the internet, Quartz reference, Stack overflow and googled for few hours so I will appreciate every tip.

Thanks - M

Comment: You do have automatic reference counting (ARC) turned on, yes?  Otherwise bridge casts would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the cast *to* `void *` (when you create the tap) is being allowed at all. Isn't the compiler giving you an error on that? [The ARC spec](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) says it's verboten.

Having a `void` pointer be your only strong reference to an object is an anti-pattern. Either that object should be the owner of (in this case) the event tap, or an object should own both the tap and the object that needs to be kept alive. Making the event tap be owned instead of the owner is much more likely to work under all memory-management schemes yet devised, and makes for cleaner code as a side benefit.

(This also goes for NSOpenPanels and NSSavePanels in pre-Blocks code.)

Comment: I was not casting to `void*` before passing parameter to callback function. I was just giving it object's address (via `&`). 

Later that day I tried to `bridge-cast` to `void*` before passing as parameter to callback function and it worked. As long as I did it only once in whole program. Otherwise some memory corruption appeared.

Thank you for you answer but, I am new to Objective-C and Cocoa so...how can I make the event tap to be owned by object (`NSFileHandle`) which I want to keep alive?

Thanks a lot - M

Comment: I found where error was. It is okay if you bridge-cast to void -> pass as parameter to callback -> inside callback bridge-cast back to original type...but what I was missing was, that I was bridge-casting to void* and passing to callback even before I initialized the object :-)    Thank you a lot and sorry for me

Comment: @user1023979: You can't make the file handle own the tap, and it wouldn't make sense from an MVC standpoint. You should make an object that owns both.